# How does the OpenGL Blend equation work?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glblendfunc

opengl ver: opengl es 1.x
platform: iphone

The blending equation:

(Rs Sr + Rd Dr, Gs Sg + Gd Dg, Bs Sb + Bd Db, As Sa + Ad Da)

How does it work?
I don't understand if I set both src and des to GL_ONE, and I have src color red (255,0,0) and des color black (0,0,0), the result will be (0,0,0)

Can someone explain how the equation work, or maybe show some calculation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set src and dst to GL_ONE, you will not get black.

The result is `(Rs + Rd, Gs + Gd, Bs + Bd)` (as Sr = Sg = Sb = Dr = Dg = Db = 1)

Which in your case of (255,0.0) and (0,0,0) will give (255,0,0).

Comment: Ya, that is what I think the result will be. I am using cocos2d and the outcome is not what I expected. So there must be something wrong with my game logic